# How to get part of total based on 2 percentages

Tags: percentages

sorry I don't know the name for this problem, nor if it's even solvable.

I'm trying to calculate the new delivery cost based on previous data.

Say we have 2 products with respective delivery cost per item:
`Apple -->  7 $` (7 -> current value)
`Melon --> 20 $` (20 -> current value)

Then, I make a purchase of:
`10 x Apple`
`50 x Melon`
Total **new** delivery fee is: `1,130 $`.

Just with the data above, is it possible to calculate and know that the **new** delivery fees are:
`Apple -->  8 $ (10 x  8 $ =    80 $)`
`Melon --> 21 $ (50 x 21 $ = 1,050 $)`

If the quantities were equal, then I could assume that `25.93% (7 / (7 + 20))` of the delivery fee belongs to Apples, and `74.07%` belongs to Melons.

But since quantities are not equal, I have this problem of 2 percentages. I can't say that `25.93 % (based on previous delivery fee)` or `16.67 % (based on quantity)` of the total belongs to Apples.

This problem comes from making purchases of big and small items. If I just take the total and divide with all quantity, then the smaller items would have their delivery cost higher than their own cost.

Thanks in advance!

**update - edit ------------**
So I got this idea, it doesn't solve what I asked, but may be good enough for you as it is for me.

Basically, calculate the total delivery fee using old values:

```
10 x Apple ( 7 $) =    70 $
50 x Melon (20 $) = 1,000 $
            total = 1,070 $
```

Then compare it with the new delivery fee: `1,130 $`

```
1,070 -> 1,130 = 5.6 % Increase
```

Now I can use that % to update the products delivery fee:

```
Apple  7 $ + 5.6 % =>  7.39 $
Melon 20 $ + 5.6 % => 21.12 $
```

This is not a solution for what I originally asked in the post (I asked poorly). But I think this might be what you were looking for if you had the same problem as I did.

Comment: btw, if anyone knows the name for this operation (in the edit section) please let me know, it would make it easier for me to explain it to others. In real world, I will use that final value and apply weighted averages (fancy word for a non-mathematic person) with current inventory quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lulu notes, you got the arithmetic in your example wrong.

In general, it's not possible, no. Here's how I know. There are two different per-apple and per-melon prices that produce the same total. So you cannot tell which of these (or some other) the right value is. For instance, in your example, the data

```
Apple -> 14
Melon -> 18.60
```

gives exactly the same total cost.

If you happen to have data for two *different* deliveries, say

```
10 Apple, 50 Melon -> 1070
 8 Apple, 32 Melon -> 696
```

then you *can*, generally, figure out the cost per apple or per melon. If you call the first of these $A$ and the second $M$, then we have

\begin{align}
10A + 50 M = 1070 \\
8A + 32 M = 696
\end{align}
We multiply the top equation by $8$ (the thing next to $A$ in the bottom one) and the bottom by 10 (the thing next to $A$ in the top one) to get
\begin{align}
80A + 400 M = 8560 \\
80A + 320 M = 6960
\end{align}
We then subtract one equation from the other to get
\begin{align}
80A + 400 M = 8560 \\
0A + 80 M = 1600
\end{align}
and now we can see that since 80M = 1600, we have $M = 20$. The first equation then becomes
\begin{align}
80A + 400 \cdot 20 = 8560 \\
80A + 8000= 8560 \\
80A = 560 \\
8A = 56 \\
A = 7 \\
\end{align}

This technique *can* fail: if one of the orders contains *zero* apples, it won't work (you'll need to do the "cross multiplying" using the numbers next to the $M$s instead!), and if the two orders are just multiples of one another, i.e. the first is 
$$
(4A, 3M)
$$
and the second is
$$
(8A, 6M)
$$
then you won't have enough information. Otherwise, this technique should work (given two orders) to discover the hidden pricing.

Warning: Often, there a delivery charge, and that messes up everything!

Comment: Thank you. I happen to find an idea to my problem, not the actual solution for what I asked, but it works for me, going to edit my post, maybe it helps someone else.